# Hover on a particular dash of a stroke

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create the following rating system using css, html and if needed js :

[image]

When the user puts his mouse on a particular dash of the circle stroke it fills all the previous dash with a particular color. For now I have done the following :

```css
* {
  background-color: blue;
}

.progress-ring__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 25 6;
}
```

```html
<svg
   class="progress-ring"
   width="120"
   height="120">
  <circle
    class="progress-ring__circle"
    stroke="grey"
    stroke-width="10"
    fill="transparent"
    r="52"
    cx="60"
    cy="60"/>
</svg>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to detect on which dash the user has his mouse on. Is there any way to do this using JS or CSS ?

Comment: You can do this task with observables: https://www.stackchief.com/tutorials/JavaScript%20Observables%20in%205%20Minutes

Comment: This is simple to do with event listeners. The problem is that you only have one element in your view. Each of the 10 dashes represented above must be their own elements that would receive their own styling (on or off color). Add 10 arcs to make your circle and then `.addEventListener('hover', ...)` to effect each individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it one way is to draw the circle with several path where you add on each path an event listener on mouseover

```js
let paths = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#progress-circle .small"));
paths.forEach(function(path) {
  path.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    target.setAttribute('style', 'stroke: blue');
    document.getElementById('percentValue').textContent = target.dataset.percent;
    
    paths.forEach(function(previousPath) {
     if (parseInt(previousPath.dataset.percent) <= parseInt(target.dataset.percent)) 
     {
        previousPath.setAttribute('style', 'stroke: blue');
     } else {
        previousPath.setAttribute('style', 'stroke: grey');
     }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
    * {
    }

    .progress-ring__circle {
      stroke-dasharray: 25 6;
    }

    .progress-ring__circle:hover {
      stroke-dasharray: 25 6;
    }

    .progress-ring__circle:nth-child(2){
        stroke: #f00; 
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;

        
        
    }
```

```html
<svg style="stroke:black; fill:none; stroke-width:2" width="400" height="400" id="progress-circle">
     <path 
        class="small"
        stroke="grey"
        stroke-width="10" 
        data-percent="1"
        d=" M 236 105 A 100 100 288 0 1 279 133" />
     <path 
        class="small"
        stroke="grey"
        stroke-width="10" 
        data-percent="2"
        d=" M 286 141 A 100 100 324 0 1 304 190" />
     <path 
        class="small"
        stroke="grey"
        stroke-width="10" 
        data-percent="3"
        d=" M 305 200 A 100 100 0 0 1 292 250" />
     <path  
        class="small"
        stroke="grey"
        stroke-width="10" 
        data-percent="4"
        d=" M 286 259 A 100 100 36 0 1 246 291" />
     <path 
        class="small"
        stroke="grey"
        stroke-width="10" 
        data-percent="5"
        d=" M 236 295 A 100 100 72 0 1 184 298" />
     <path 
        class="small"
        stroke="grey"
        stroke-width="10" 
        data-percent="6"
        d=" M 174 295 A 100 100 108 0 1 131 267" />
     <path 
        class="small"
        stroke="grey"
        stroke-width="10" 
        data-percent="7"
        d=" M 124 259 A 100 100 144 0 1 106 210" />
     <path 
        class="small"
        stroke="grey"
        stroke-width="10" 
        data-percent="8"
        d=" M 105 200 A 100 100 180 0 1 118 150" />
     <path 
        class="small"
        stroke="grey"
        stroke-width="10" 
        data-percent="9"
        d=" M 124 141 A 100 100 216 0 1 164 109" />
     <path 
        class="small"
        stroke="grey"
        stroke-width="10" 
        data-percent="10"
        d=" M 174 105 A 100 100 252 0 1 226 102" />
</path>
<text id="percentValue" x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">0</text>    
 </svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much !  I actually didn't think about doing it this way, but I think it's needed to actually separate dashes